# BufferedInputStream Mark/Reset invalid mark

Tags: java, bufferedinputstream

I have 2 BufferedInputStreams which both contain an xml string: one small one, and one very large.

Here's how the beginning of each of these xml strings looks like:

```
<RootElement success="true">
```

I created a method which:

1. Sets the mark at the beginning of the inputstream
2. Reads the first few bytes of the xml to check if the root element has a specific attrribute.
3. Reset the inputstream to the mark position, so another method can enjoy the complete full stream.

I was under the impression that the size of neither the buffer of the buffered input stream (default is 8012bytes) nor the mark readlimit would actually matter because I'm only reading like the first 50 bytes before resetting regardless of how large my inputstream is.

Unfortunately I get a "`IOException: resseting to invalid mark`" exception. Here's the relevant code:

```
private boolean checkXMLForSuccess(BufferedInputStream responseStream) throws XMLStreamException, FactoryConfigurationError
{
    //Normally, this should be set to the amount of bytes that can be read before invalidating.
    //the mark. Because we use a default buffer size (1024 or 2048 bytes) that is much greater
    //than the amount of bytes we will read here (less than 100 bytes) this is not a concern.
    responseStream.mark(100);

    XMLStreamReader xmlReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(responseStream);
    xmlReader.next(); //Go to the root element

    //This is for loop, but the root element can only have 1 attribute.
    for (int i=0; i < xmlReader.getAttributeCount(); i++)
    {
        if(xmlReader.getAttributeLocalName(i).equals(SUCCES_ATTRIBUTE))
        {
            Boolean isSuccess = Boolean.parseBoolean(xmlReader.getAttributeValue(i));

            if (isSuccess)
            {
                try
                {
                    responseStream.reset();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    //Oh oh... reset mark problem??
                }

                return true; 
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now, of course I tried setting the mark read limit to a higher number. I had to set it to a value of 10000 before it finally worked. I cannot imagine my code below needs to read 10000 bytes! What other factors could be responsible for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Documentation of InputStream class - reset() method:

> public void reset()
>              throws IOException
>
> The general contract of reset is:
>   If the method markSupported returns true, then:
>   If the number of bytes read from the stream since mark was
>   last called is larger than the argument to mark at that last call,
>   then an IOException might be thrown.

In your code,

You have passed 100 as the byte read limit.

```
responseStream.mark(100);
```

and there is a very high probability the part of the code:

```
xmlReader.next();
```

reads more than 100 bytes, and the mark being invalidated and a call to the reset() method throwing an IOException.

> XMLStreamReader.next():
>
> Get next parsing event - a processor may return all contiguous 
>   character data in a single chunk, or it may split it into several
>   chunks

So, the reader could have kept reading more than the read limit bytes causing the mark to be invalidated. (This happens irrespective of the file size, and if the contiguous characters are large).

Second instance,

> If the method markSupported returns false, then:
>   The call to reset may throw an IOException

but the BufferedInputStream supports marking,

> public boolean markSupported()
>
> Tests if this input stream supports the mark and reset methods. The
>   markSupported method of BufferedInputStream returns true.

So the second case can be cut down.

Comment: if xmlReader.next() reads more than 100 bytes, why does the small xml file of size 500 bytes DOES work, but the large xml of size 5000 does not work? both have the same root element with the same attribute and both are larger than 100 bytes.

Comment: @user1884155 At this point, without actually looking at what XMLReader is doing in the OpenJDK code, it's all going to be speculation.

Comment: @user1884155,@Powerlord - Have updated my answer wrt your comments

Comment: @user1884155 can you check if there are contiguous characters in your file occupying > 100 bytes

Comment: I found something strange. When I output the xml to my eclipse console, I see there's a huge mount of whitepace appearing out of nowhere. If I trim my string the whitespace remains. If i print out the string char by char, there is no whitespace anywhere. I don't know what weird character is cuasing this behaviour. Non-trimmable whitespace gaps of 1000's spaces long?!

Comment: I think this might help you - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/wang-whitespace-092897.html.They may be carriage returns and line feeds read in between texts.

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but the `XMLStreamReader` is likely reading a large part of the `InputStream` during the `getAttributeCount` or `getAttributeLocalName` methods, although it's possible that it's being done when the XMLStreamReader is created...

I haven't looked through the OpenJDK code to confirm this, though.